# Define possible?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policies

In Reinforcement Learning, policies are defined in terms of *possible* actions (see for instance page 58 of the book by Sutton et al.). So, is any action that an agent has in its repertoire always "possible", even when it has a policy-value of zero? Or are possible actions dependent on the state?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Suppose that the action space is defined as $\mathcal{A} = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and the state space is $\mathcal{S} = \{a, b, c\}$. If we can only take actions $1$ and $2$ in state $a$ then what this means is that any policy must have $p(3 | a) = 0$ by definition. Here I guess I am trying to emphasise that whilst action $3$ is still part of the action space for state $a$, it is not a _possible_ action, and so any policy must assign 0 probability to selecting it.

Comment: Clear. Thank you.